# Transferring data from old dedicated server to a new one

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, migration, file-transfer, dedicated-server

I have a Windows 2003 dedicated server account with WebFusion and they are just awful, I'm not afraid to say. I would like to transfer to a GoDaddy Windows 2008 dedicated server in the next week or two , but struggle to see how we're going to transfer our 360,000 image files. At the same time, trying to keep it synchronized. If we can't synchronize it's not the end of the world, we can do it without that, but it would be nice.

We don't have a good enough internet connection for this transfer via FTP, and we've asked GoDaddy if they offer a file transfer service but they don't.

Can anybody suggest how we can go about this the right way? I have administrator access to our current server but my knowledge is somewhat limited, as all I do is update components and write schedules, but I thought there may be away of transferring them from the server itself, using the data centre connection.

Transferring databases, rebuilding schedules, reinstalling components and other settings is not a problem for us, it's just the huge bunch of image files we're concerned about.

Any help gratefully received as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `robocopy /mir c:\source \\server\destination /r:2`, which will mirror the folders between targets. You can let this run for a long time. When you re-run the same command, it will copy only the delta. This will allow you to stage the directory with most of the images and then quickly copy only the changes right before you cut over to the new box.